# Double ToString keeping "en-US" format

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, globalization

Sounds simples - And I know it is... but i'm having issues with it and don't know why exactly..

I have a web application globalized (multilanguages).
When I click to change the language, this is my action:

```
public ActionResult ChangeCulture(string lang)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

    var languageCookie = new HttpCookie("_language") { Value = lang, Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1) };

    Response.Cookies.Remove("_language");
    Response.SetCookie(languageCookie);

    return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);
}
```

And I have a page to display some char (I'm using [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/)) and I need to bind a `List<double>` to a javascript array.

So this list looks like:

```
var list = new List<double> {144, 0, 540.23};
```

And I need a simples array in javascript:

```
var arr = [144, 0, 540.23];
```

Here is how I'm doing (razor):

```
var arr = [@string.Join(",", Model.ListWithDoubles.Select(x => Convert.ToString(x, new CultureInfo("en-US"))))]
```

The problem is:

When I'm using english language its works pretty. The others langues gives me integer numbers instead...

```
var arr = [144, 0, 540.23]; //en-US
var arr = [144, 0, 54023]; //pt-BR 
var arr = [144, 0, 54023]; //it
var arr = [144, 0, 54023]; //es
```

**Questions**

1. Why?
2. How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in some other non `en-US` cultures the `,` and `.` have the exact opposite meaning and usage. If you are not displaying this data, only for chart purposes, then use [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx) when converting the double to string representation for the HTML. You should only convert to a culture specific string at the point you want to actually visually display that data value to the user.

```
var arr = [@string.Join(",", Model.ListWithDoubles.Select(x => Convert.ToString(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))]
```

The default format specifier for `double` is `G` so it will create output with only a decimal separator. As you want the raw number (not formatted for display) then this ([CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx)) is what you need to pass, not the culture formatted string representation as that is for display only.

---

To illustrate that the code I posted works regardless of the culture of the current thread here is that code. Drop this into a console application and replace the `Main` method and run it. You will see that this works. Your issue lies elsewhere, not with this code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cultures = new[] {"en-US", "pt-BR", "it", "es"};
    var list = new List<double> {144, 0, 540.23};

    Console.WriteLine("Without specifying a culture");

    foreach (var culture in cultures.Select(isoCulture => new CultureInfo(isoCulture)))
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

        Console.WriteLine("Culture: " + culture.Name);

        Console.WriteLine("Not defined:                  " + string.Join(",", list.Select(x => Convert.ToString(x))));
        Console.WriteLine("CultureInfo.InvariantCulture: " + string.Join(",", list.Select(x => Convert.ToString(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))));
    }
    Console.ReadLine(); // stops so you can see the results
}
```

Comment: I tried this already and it doesn't work.... I think its because I change the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` when I change the site language..

Comment: @MarllonNasser - it does work, (make sure you compiled and published your code with the latest changes). Even the example on the Microsoft documentation shows this exact same method so if it did not work there would have been many other complaints about this functionality prior to your question. See example on page [Convert.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131010(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @MarllonNasser - this does assume that `Model.ListWithDoubles` is in fact of type `List<double>` or at least something that implements `IEnumerable<double>`

Comment: but it is type `List<double>` as I said: `var list = new List<double> {144, 0, 540.23};` This is my `ListWithDoubles`. sorry

Comment: @MarllonNasser - maybe you need to explain what you mean by `... and it doesn't work`. If you open the HTML source in the browser you should see the array with the correct values. Also if you debug you should see the correct values being passed. Maybe there is a failure at a different point that is being confused with the problem above.

Comment: I understand @Igor, but I'm showing everything I have... this is what I got on debug (c#): `ListWithDoubles = new List<double> {144, 0, 540.23};`. But when it goes to razor with the proper conversion, show me differents values when its not `en-US`. The output of the question it's the same using your approach. :(

Comment: @MarllonNasser - it must be your razor view or its output being cached by your controller. Trust me, this code above works. Add something bogus to it hard coded along with the change I have above. If your bogus output does not render then you know its your view update not being pulled from the server.

Comment: I did that... I put this: `[@Convert.ToString(2.56, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)]` and it printed: `[2.56]` as it should....... so... no clue yet :(

Comment: So that works, exactly as it should with a `.` to separate the decimal from the whole number. What exactly is `not working` then?

Comment: that's the problem in fact... `[@Convert.ToString(2.56, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)]` this works but this: `var list = new List<double> {144, 0, 540.23}; var arr = [@string.Join(",", list .Select(x => Convert.ToString(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))]`

Comment: I just couldn't accept anymore this kind of error... taking a loot where my List of double was binded I noticed that I converted to Double without CultureInfo.. `DoubleValue = Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToString(dr["data_row_double"]).Replace(",", "."))`so I added and it finally works... thanks mate!